# Spring Boot 2.6 App on WildFly 19 - Can't reach my app

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, wildfly

I have a Java API Spring Boot application (2.6.0-SNAPSHOT) without any context, also have a FrontEnd written in VueJS on path `/src/main/resources/static`, in my local development environment when i run the project, i can view the FrontEnd app over the url `localhost:8080` and can access to my API project in Spring Boot over the url for example `localhost:8080/security/myEndpoint`, and everything works well.

Now i need to deploy my project on WildFly 19 application server (wildfly-19.0.0.Final), first i'm using maven to build the war file and then put it into `\standalone\deployments\` path to deploy.

When i'm execute `standalone` file to start the deploy the server do all the process and starts ok, but i'm trying to access to my front app or my API Endpoints and get 404 error.

What is missing on this configuration to get the same functioning that on my development environment?

My pom.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.co.myapp</groupId>
<artifactId>RED</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>RED</name>
<description>My app</description>
<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-ldap</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-quartz</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
      <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.10</version>
   </dependency>
    
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                    </exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </releases>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </releases>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

Main Class

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
@PropertySource(value = "file:${spring.config.location}/applicationconfig.properties")
@PropertySource(value = "file:${spring.config.location}/propiedades.properties")
public class BackRedApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    return application.sources(BackRedApplication.class);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(BackRedApplication.class, args);
}

@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer placeHolderConfigurer() {
   return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
}
}
```

My application.properties

```
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=250MB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=250MB
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans=true
#spring.profiles.active=dev
#spring.profiles.active=test
#spring.config.location=path_to_my_spring_configuration
#server.servlet.context-path=/api-red

#
#spring.mvc.static-path-pattern=/uploads/**
#spring.web.resources.static-locations=file:/opt/files
```

My applicationconfig.properties (defined on main class)

```
#
spring.datasource.jdbc-url=jdbc:mysql://mydb.com:3306/MYDB
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
server.port = 8080

springdoc.packagesToScan=the_package_to_scan
#springdoc.pathsToMatch=/v1, /api/balance/**

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true

#Generate camelCase columns names in DB as delcared in Entities
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical- 
strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl

logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
#logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE
```

Part of WildFly Log

```
2021-10-26 00:47:21,142 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 92) ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \

2021-10-26 00:47:21,142 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 92)  \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )

2021-10-26 00:47:21,142 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 92)   '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /

2021-10-26 00:47:21,143 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 92)  =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/

2021-10-26 00:47:21,143 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 92)  :: Spring Boot ::       (v2.6.0-SNAPSHOT)

2021-10-26 00:47:21,144 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 92) 

2021-10-26 00:47:21,146 INFO  [org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version] (background-preinit) HV000001: Hibernate Validator 6.0.18.Final
2021-10-26 00:47:21,186 INFO  [com.co.dejsoftware.red.BackRedApplication] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 92) Starting BackRedApplication using Java 11.0.12 on DAVID-DESKTOP with PID 4500 (started by david in C:\Users\david\Documents\Emprendimiento\CLIENTES_EXTERNOS\UTADEO\wildfly-19.0.0.Final\bin)
2021-10-26 00:47:21,187 INFO  [com.co.dejsoftware.red.BackRedApplication] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 92) No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2021-10-26 00:47:21,635 INFO  [org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 92) Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict repository configuration mode!
2021-10-26 00:47:21,637 INFO  [org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 92) Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2021-10-26 00:47:21,706 INFO  [org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 92) Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 62 ms. Found 8 JPA repository interfaces.
2021-10-26 00:47:21,712 INFO  [org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 92) Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict repository configuration mode!
2021-10-26 00:47:21,713 INFO  [org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 92) Bootstrapping Spring Data LDAP repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2021-10-26 00:47:21,725 INFO  [org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 92) Spring Data LDAP - Could not safely identify store assignment for repository candidate interface com.co.dejsoftware.red.repositorios.job.RepositorioCampaniasImportadas. If you want this repository to be a LDAP repository, consider annotating your entities with one of these annotations: org.springframework.ldap.odm.annotations.Entry (preferred), or consider extending one of the following types with your repository: org.springframework.data.ldap.repository.LdapRepository.
2021-10-26 00:47:21,726 INFO  [org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 92) Spring Data LDAP - Could not safely identify store assignment for repository candidate interface com.co.dejsoftware.red.repositorios.RepositorioDomain. If you want this repository to be a LDAP repository, consider annotating your entities with one of these annotations: org.springframework.ldap.odm.annotations.Entry (preferred), or consider extending one of the following types with your repository: org.springframework.data.ldap.repository.LdapRepository.
2021-10-26 00:47:21,726 INFO  [org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 92) Spring Data LDAP - Could not safely identify store assignment for repository candidate interface com.co.dejsoftware.red.repositorios.RepositorioRol. If you want this repository to be a LDAP repository, consider annotating your entities with one of these annotations: org.springframework.ldap.odm.annotations.Entry (preferred), or consider extending one of the following types with your repository: org.springframework.data.ldap.repository.LdapRepository.
2021-10-26 00:47:21,727 INFO  [org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 92) Spring Data LDAP - Could not safely identify store assignment for repository candidate interface com.co.dejsoftware.red.repositorios.RepositorioSurvey. If you want this repository to be a LDAP repository, consider annotating your entities with one of these annotations: org.springframework.ldap.odm.annotations.Entry (preferred), or consider extending one of the following types with your repository: org.springframework.data.ldap.repository.LdapRepository.
2021-10-26 00:47:21,727 INFO  [org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 92) Spring Data LDAP - Could not safely identify store assignment for repository candidate interface com.co.dejsoftware.red.repositorios.RepositorioSurveyQuestion. If you want this repository to be a LDAP repository, consider annotating your entities with one of these annotations: org.springframework.ldap.odm.annotations.Entry (preferred), or consider extending one of the following types with your repository: org.springframework.data.ldap.repository.LdapRepository.
2021-10-26 00:47:21,728 INFO  [org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 92) Spring Data LDAP - Could not safely identify store assignment for repository candidate interface com.co.dejsoftware.red.repositorios.RepositorioSurveyQuestionAnswer. If you want this repository to be a LDAP repository, consider annotating your entities with one of these annotations: org.springframework.ldap.odm.annotations.Entry (preferred), or consider extending one of the following types with your repository: org.springframework.data.ldap.repository.LdapRepository.
2021-10-26 00:47:21,729 INFO  [org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 92) Spring Data LDAP - Could not safely identify store assignment for repository candidate interface com.co.dejsoftware.red.repositorios.RepositorioSurveyQuestionAttribute. If you want this repository to be a LDAP repository, consider annotating your entities with one of these annotations: org.springframework.ldap.odm.annotations.Entry (preferred), or consider extending one of the following types with your repository: org.springframework.data.ldap.repository.LdapRepository.
2021-10-26 00:47:21,729 INFO  [org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 92) Spring Data LDAP - Could not safely identify store assignment for repository candidate interface com.co.dejsoftware.red.repositorios.RepositorioUsers. If you want this repository to be a LDAP repository, consider annotating your entities with one of these annotations: org.springframework.ldap.odm.annotations.Entry (preferred), or consider extending one of the following types with your repository: org.springframework.data.ldap.repository.LdapRepository.
2021-10-26 00:47:21,729 INFO  [org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 92) Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 15 ms. Found 0 LDAP repository interfaces.
2021-10-26 00:47:21,978 INFO  [io.undertow.servlet] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 92) Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2021-10-26 00:47:21,979 INFO  [org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 92) Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 773 ms
2021-10-26 00:47:22,145 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 92) Loading class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'. This is deprecated. The new driver class is `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'. The driver is automatically registered via the SPI and manual loading of the driver class is generally unnecessary.

2021-10-26 00:47:22,253 INFO  [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 92) HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2021-10-26 00:47:22,301 INFO  [org.hibernate.Version] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 92) HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.6.0.Final
2021-10-26 00:47:22,424 INFO  [org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 92) HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2021-10-26 00:47:22,493 INFO  [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 92) HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2021-10-26 00:47:22,497 WARN  [com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 92) Registered driver with driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver was not found, trying direct instantiation.
2021-10-26 00:47:23,851 INFO  [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 92) HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2021-10-26 00:47:23,862 INFO  [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 92) HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
2021-10-26 00:47:23,988 INFO  [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.JtaPlatformInitiator] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 92) HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringJtaPlatform]
2021-10-26 00:47:30,064 INFO  [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 92) Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2021-10-26 00:47:30,896 WARN  [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 92) spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2021-10-26 00:47:31,104 INFO  [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WelcomePageHandlerMapping] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 92) Adding welcome page: class path resource [static/index.html]
2021-10-26 00:47:32,432 INFO  [org.springframework.ldap.core.support.AbstractContextSource] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 92) Property 'userDn' not set - anonymous context will be used for read-write operations
2021-10-26 00:47:32,481 INFO  [org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 92) Using default implementation for ThreadExecutor
2021-10-26 00:47:32,494 INFO  [org.quartz.core.SchedulerSignalerImpl] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 92) Initialized Scheduler Signaller of type: class org.quartz.core.SchedulerSignalerImpl
2021-10-26 00:47:32,495 INFO  [org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 92) Quartz Scheduler v.2.3.2 created.
2021-10-26 00:47:32,496 INFO  [org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 92) RAMJobStore initialized.
2021-10-26 00:47:32,497 INFO  [org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 92) Scheduler meta-data: Quartz Scheduler (v2.3.2) 'quartzScheduler' with instanceId 'NON_CLUSTERED'
  Scheduler class: 'org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler' - running locally.
  NOT STARTED.
  Currently in standby mode.
  Number of jobs executed: 0
  Using thread pool 'org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool' - with 10 threads.
  Using job-store 'org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore' - which does not support persistence. and is not clustered.

2021-10-26 00:47:32,497 INFO  [org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 92) Quartz scheduler 'quartzScheduler' initialized from an externally provided properties instance.
2021-10-26 00:47:32,498 INFO  [org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 92) Quartz scheduler version: 2.3.2
2021-10-26 00:47:32,498 INFO  [org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 92) JobFactory set to: org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SpringBeanJobFactory@435e5276
2021-10-26 00:47:32,527 INFO  [org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 92) Starting Quartz Scheduler now
2021-10-26 00:47:32,528 INFO  [org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 92) Scheduler quartzScheduler_$_NON_CLUSTERED started.
2021-10-26 00:47:32,542 INFO  [com.co.dejsoftware.red.BackRedApplication] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 92) Started BackRedApplication in 11.605 seconds (JVM running for 19.378)
2021-10-26 00:47:32,545 INFO  [com.co.dejsoftware.red.ServletInitializer] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 92) Root context already created (using as parent).
2021-10-26 00:47:32,582 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 92) 

2021-10-26 00:47:32,583 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 92)   .   ____          _            __ _ _

2021-10-26 00:47:32,585 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 92)  /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \

2021-10-26 00:47:32,590 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 92) ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \

2021-10-26 00:47:32,591 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 92)  \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )

2021-10-26 00:47:32,591 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 92)   '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /

2021-10-26 00:47:32,592 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 92)  =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/

2021-10-26 00:47:32,592 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 92)  :: Spring Boot ::       (v2.6.0-SNAPSHOT)

2021-10-26 00:47:32,593 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 92) 

2021-10-26 00:47:32,596 INFO  [com.co.dejsoftware.red.ServletInitializer] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 92) No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2021-10-26 00:47:32,777 INFO  [org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 92) Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict repository configuration mode!
2021-10-26 00:47:32,777 INFO  [org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 92) Bootstrapping Spring Data LDAP repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2021-10-26 00:47:32,791 INFO  [org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 92) Spring Data LDAP - Could not safely identify store assignment for repository candidate interface com.co.dejsoftware.red.repositorios.job.RepositorioCampaniasImportadas. If you want this repository to be a LDAP repository, consider annotating your entities with one of these annotations: org.springframework.ldap.odm.annotations.Entry (preferred), or consider extending one of the following types with your repository: org.springframework.data.ldap.repository.LdapRepository.
2021-10-26 00:47:32,792 INFO  [org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 92) Spring Data LDAP - Could not safely identify store assignment for repository candidate interface com.co.dejsoftware.red.repositorios.RepositorioDomain. If you want this repository to be a LDAP repository, consider annotating your entities with one of these annotations: org.springframework.ldap.odm.annotations.Entry (preferred), or consider extending one of the following types with your repository: org.springframework.data.ldap.repository.LdapRepository.
2021-10-26 00:47:32,793 INFO  [org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 92) Spring Data LDAP - Could not safely identify store assignment for repository candidate interface com.co.dejsoftware.red.repositorios.RepositorioRol. If you want this repository to be a LDAP repository, consider annotating your entities with one of these annotations: org.springframework.ldap.odm.annotations.Entry (preferred), or consider extending one of the following types with your repository: org.springframework.data.ldap.repository.LdapRepository.
2021-10-26 00:47:32,793 INFO  [org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 92) Spring Data LDAP - Could not safely identify store assignment for repository candidate interface com.co.dejsoftware.red.repositorios.RepositorioSurvey. If you want this repository to be a LDAP repository, consider annotating your entities with one of these annotations: org.springframework.ldap.odm.annotations.Entry (preferred), or consider extending one of the following types with your repository: org.springframework.data.ldap.repository.LdapRepository.
2021-10-26 00:47:32,794 INFO  [org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 92) Spring Data LDAP - Could not safely identify store assignment for repository candidate interface com.co.dejsoftware.red.repositorios.RepositorioSurveyQuestion. If you want this repository to be a LDAP repository, consider annotating your entities with one of these annotations: org.springframework.ldap.odm.annotations.Entry (preferred), or consider extending one of the following types with your repository: org.springframework.data.ldap.repository.LdapRepository.
2021-10-26 00:47:32,794 INFO  [org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 92) Spring Data LDAP - Could not safely identify store assignment for repository candidate interface com.co.dejsoftware.red.repositorios.RepositorioSurveyQuestionAnswer. If you want this repository to be a LDAP repository, consider annotating your entities with one of these annotations: org.springframework.ldap.odm.annotations.Entry (preferred), or consider extending one of the following types with your repository: org.springframework.data.ldap.repository.LdapRepository.
2021-10-26 00:47:32,795 INFO  [org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 92) Spring Data LDAP - Could not safely identify store assignment for repository candidate interface com.co.dejsoftware.red.repositorios.RepositorioSurveyQuestionAttribute. If you want this repository to be a LDAP repository, consider annotating your entities with one of these annotations: org.springframework.ldap.odm.annotations.Entry (preferred), or consider extending one of the following types with your repository: org.springframework.data.ldap.repository.LdapRepository.
2021-10-26 00:47:32,795 INFO  [org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 92) Spring Data LDAP - Could not safely identify store assignment for repository candidate interface com.co.dejsoftware.red.repositorios.RepositorioUsers. If you want this repository to be a LDAP repository, consider annotating your entities with one of these annotations: org.springframework.ldap.odm.annotations.Entry (preferred), or consider extending one of the following types with your repository: org.springframework.data.ldap.repository.LdapRepository.
2021-10-26 00:47:32,795 INFO  [org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 92) Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 16 ms. Found 0 LDAP repository interfaces.
2021-10-26 00:47:32,823 INFO  [io.undertow.servlet] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 92) Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2021-10-26 00:47:32,823 INFO  [org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 92) Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 221 ms
2021-10-26 00:47:32,830 INFO  [org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.RegistrationBean] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 92) Filter errorPageFilter was not registered (possibly already registered?)
2021-10-26 00:47:32,830 INFO  [org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.RegistrationBean] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 92) Filter vueRoutePathFilter was not registered (possibly already registered?)
2021-10-26 00:47:32,915 INFO  [com.co.dejsoftware.red.ServletInitializer] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 92) Started ServletInitializer in 0.368 seconds (JVM running for 19.751)
2021-10-26 00:47:32,957 INFO  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 92) Initializing Mojarra 2.3.9.SP06 for context '/api-red'
2021-10-26 00:47:34,146 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 92) WFLYUT0021: Registered web context: '/api-red' for server 'default-server'
2021-10-26 00:47:34,177 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 45) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "RED-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war" (runtime-name : "RED-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war")
2021-10-26 00:47:34,204 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0212: Resuming server
2021-10-26 00:47:34,206 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0060: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990/management
2021-10-26 00:47:34,207 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0051: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
2021-10-26 00:47:34,208 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0025: WildFly Full 19.0.0.Final (WildFly Core 11.0.0.Final) started in 20962ms - Started 539 of 768 services (379 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
```

WildFly standalone.xml

[image]

VueJS App path on Spring Boot Project:

[image]

FrontEnd on my Local Development Environment

[image]

BackEnd on my Local Development Environment

[image]

WildFly Environment Execution

[image]

FrontEnd over WildFly Environment Execution

[image]

BackEnd over WildFly Environment Execution

[image]

Comment: Is there more to the log?  Can you see which port wildfly is using?  I dont think it is the same 8080

Comment: Is there a good reason why you use SNAPSHOT versions of spring boot instead of releases?

Comment: I'm using this version because is the last one available, nothing special, also on the question i added the log of wildfly

Comment: the port of wildfly is default (8080) also added part of standalone.xml file

Comment: The current available version for 2.6.X is [2.6.0-RC1](https://spring.io/blog/2021/10/21/spring-boot-2-6-0-rc1-is-available-now) furthermore there had several milestones before (m1...m3)...which is available from central repository. I would always to recommend to use those instead of SNAPSHOT's... Furthermore there are releases of 2.5.X line available (2.5.4, 2.5.5).. so I don't understand the usage of SNAPSHOT..

Answer (score 0):

Could you try the following maven dependency changes:

```
 <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <!-- We need to include the javax.servlet API specs, the implementation 
         will be provided by Wildfly / JBoss / Tomcat -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
...
```

Instead of

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    <scope>provide</scope>
</dependency>
```